# How to access List type from an option set in conditions of the Rules module?

Tags: commerce, entities, rules

Iam trying to access an option set(weight_options) within which we have a List type that holds weight , represented as below

```
 "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-product" ],
 "field" : "field_weight_options"
```

**field_weight_options** is a option set within which we have a **field_weight** which is a List type that holds values like 1lb , 2lb etc

I was able to drill through till
`commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field_weight_options:set-id` 
(which is a option set), using Data Comparison within the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

I am not able to figure out how to access the list **field_weight** and its **values**  Eg: 1lb , 2lb which are with in the option set using Data Comparison within rules module.

Any help/pointers?

Answer (score 0):

These are the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Conditions you should use:

- ***Entity has field*** "`field_weight_options`", which is the machine name of the field you want to check.
- ***List contains item*** (for your `field_weight_options`, which is a list since it is a multi value field) and with the value (such as "`2lb`") you want to check for.

What is crucial in the context of this question, are these 2 Rules Conditions. Especially because of your "`field_weight_options` is a multiple value" (only "List contains item" is the Rules Condition that will do the trick ...).

PS: This answer applies to D7.

Comment: HI Pierre , Thanks for your inputs . field_weight_options is of type Pricing Attributes which has the option set reference(Weight Option Set) . The option set ( Products » Option Sets » Weight Option Set) has field_weight which is of type List , which has the actual weight values. So if i drill through till field_weight_options , its not recognizing it as a list and the list contains item is not working

Comment: This start to sound like you ALSO need a Rules "Loop" (as a rules Action), and then inside that loop you need to add a condition similar to what I suggested. Am I coming closer? If not can you think of a way to improve your question to further clarify the confusing part about "weight options" versus "weight option sets"? Maybe with an export of a partially working rule so that based on the machine names you use the confusing part is resolved? After you do, I'll try to further rework/improve my answer also.

Comment: @Swaroop : extra clarification request (I'm trying to understand your question using Drupal terminology, and rules, not "commerce" terminology) ... Your ***option set***, how is that implemented in Drupal terminology. Just a wild guess: is that a "field collection" (= Drupal terminology)? If not then what else does its implementation look like? PS: if it is a field collection, then I know how to refine/expand my answer (and I understand you're confused about that when it comes to Rules processing ...).